# Automating splitting of an image between pages in inDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm going to be printing from inDesign onto a borderless printer. I want images that bleed over from one page onto the next to continue without a gap. The document is too long to use vertical page spreads (max 10 pages) and tiling isn't working (inDesign puts in a gap with a crop mark and slug info even though I've unchecked these).

Is there any way to get linked text boxes with inline images to span multiple boxes, with part of the image in each text box?

Answer (score 1):

Export the document from InDesign as a PDF, then in Acrobat use the Poster option in the print dialog. Depending on your printer driver, the Poster option may be unavailable (my HP printer works with this, my Canon 9000 doesn't). If that's the case, select PDF as your printer, then print the resulting multi-page PDF.

That should get you where you need to go.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, it is not working. I can print as a poster, but the bottom and top of each page is getting clipped, so part of the image is missing if it falls in between virtual page cuts. I've set the overlap to 0in but that doesn't help.

Comment: That may be a limitation of the printer. "Borderless" printing is usually accomplished by enlarging the image slightly so that it is larger than the paper, to allow for slight errors in paper transport, in much the same way that bleed on press compensates for feed and trim errors. That results in a part of the image being cut off.